# How to highlight the current row in MS Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to highlight the current/active row, so that you can easily read the document like UltraEdit?

Please see below picture:

[image]

Update:
I mean how to "automatically" highlight the current row with the cursor moving. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the left side of a row when your mouse cursor becomes mirrored to select the entire row, but I'm not sure if that increases the readability. Drag there to select multiple rows.

You may need to change your windows settings for highlight to change its colors.

Comment: I mean how to "automatically" highlight the current row with the cursor moving. Thanks.